# Head Banging Against Wall Trying to Reset Root password on MySQL

Tags: mysql, passwords

i've reset root passwords on MySQL before, and creating a file in /tmp with the appropriate command and then starting mysqld pointing to that file always worked.  Why they changed it, well .. no idea.

I only need this database for a short time, to test something.  For context -- CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009.

```
[root@laptop ~]# mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

OK, so I recall that there is a password created when I installed..

```
[root@laptop ~]# grep -i temporary /var/log/mysqld.log
2022-02-16T14:29:18.624653Z 6 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: 4=b)fmkPhWAj
```

That should work, right?

```
[root@laptop ~]# mysql -u root -p4=b)fmkPhWAj
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)
```

Nope.

```
[root@laptop ~]# systemctl stop mysqld
```

And then..

```
[root@laptop ~]# cat /tmp/tempmysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'NewPassword1';
```

And then..

```
mysqld --init-file=/tmp/tempmysql --user=mysql &
```

This gives..

```
[root@laptop ~]# mysql -u root -p2022-04-27T12:15:24.782969Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 1649
2022-04-27T12:15:25.881427Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
grep -i temporarymysql -u root -p2022-04-27T12:15:25.881799Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-04-27T12:15:26.201505Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

So at this point, I am blocked.  Can someone please tell me how one now resets a root password on a MySQL 8 install?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the password in double quotes

Because

```
echo -p4=b)fmkPhWAj
```

fails also with: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token` )'`

but:

```
echo -p4="b)fmkPhWAj"
```

will simply echo `-p4=b)fmkPhWAj`

But for resetting, the procudure described in the manual should work, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Doesn't work.  

[confluence@laptop ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[confluence@laptop ~]$ mysql -u root -p"4=b)fmkPhWAj"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: mysql -u root -p4="b)fmkPhWAj"

Comment: Fails too ..    don't know what is wrong here

Comment: you might need: `mysql -u root -p="NewPassword1"` ?

Comment: so, please restart the complete process of resetting your password.